# How to Create Custom Record in netesuit using Suitetalk in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, netsuite

How to Create Custom Record in netsuite through Suitetalk in C#?

Answer (score 3):

```
CustomRecord rec = new CustomRecord();

RecordRef recType = new RecordRef();
recType.internalId = "10"; // Internal ID of custom record type, not individual record id
recType.type = RecordType.customRecord;
recType.typeSpecified = true;

rec.recType = recType;
rec.name = "My new custom record";

CustomFieldRef[] customFieldArray = new CustomFieldRef[1];

StringCustomFieldRef stringField = new StringCustomFieldRef();
stringField.scriptId = "custrecord_string";
stringField.value = "A string";
customFieldArray[0] = stringField;

rec.customFieldList = customFieldArray;

WriteResponse response = _service.add(rec);
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this using the custom record type ID and not its internalid?